# Need POI Category Search Clarification

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I think Azure Mapping API Service does not return any data for a search using Military Zip Codes. Is that correct? Also, which POI categories or query terms would provide search results for the following:

the standard ZIP Code, which refers to a post office for a city or a division of a city that has mail service

the P.O.-Box-only type is used for P.O. boxes at various facilities

unique ZIP Code types given to organizations that receive large quantities of mail

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately today we don't support military zip codes. To submit feature requests, please go to  [Azure Maps Feedback (UserVoice):](https://aka.ms/AzureMapsFeedback)

To search zip codes, you can for example call our Get Search Address API (https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddress), if you know that your input is zip code or an address.

For example, you can use the following query to search zip codes:

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?subscription-key=[your_key]&api-version=1.0&query=98007&countrySet=US

Comment: What about P.O. Box?